# Bokeh time series plotting

Tags: python, pandas, plot, charts, bokeh

I have a bunch of time series objects I'm charting with `bokeh.charts.TimeSeries` data that I want to make into a beautiful plot with a description and title, etc. How can I add a chart to a `bokeh.plotting.figure` object? I'm using `bokeh.layouts.row` to organise them, but I want to make it look more professional than a webpage with nothing but a chart.

Is this possible? I was looking at the plotting interface, but I don't see a time series API. Would I just use my `pandas.Series` objects as the data for the line API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old `bokeh.charts` API, including `TimeSeries` was deprecated and subsequently removed. You can and should plot time series using the stable `bokeh.plotting` API. Here is a complete example created with Bokeh `0.13.0`:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.sampledata.glucose import data

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", title="Glocose Range", plot_height=350, plot_width=800)
p.xgrid.grid_line_color=None
p.ygrid.grid_line_alpha=0.5
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Time'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Value'

p.line(week.index, week.glucose)

show(p)
```

[image]